# Change TFSService password

Tags: tfs-2015

We would like to change the password for our TFSService account.  This is the domain account that was used install TFS and has several Windows services running under it.

I did review the link below on changing the TFS service password.   Is it as simple as updating the password in Active Directory and then using the TFS administration console to update the account password?   Are both steps above required?   Are there any additional tasks required?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/change-service-account-password

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should just be that.

As with any production environment, there may things in your setup strangers on the internet are not aware of, so it would be best to test this process on a non-production copy if possible first.

Although I know setting up a non-production copy of TFS will end up probably end up running on a different domain.